# Oracle JDeveloper 12c app fails when run in debug mode

Tags: weblogic, jdeveloper

When I run a JSF app (in debug mode) through Jdeveloper 12.1.2 sometimes it fails with the following error:

```
<1 Φεβ 2017 2:27:51 μμ EET> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to STANDBY.> 
<1 Φεβ 2017 2:27:51 μμ EET> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to STARTING.> 
<1 Φεβ 2017 2:28:25 μμ EET> <Warning> <oracle.adf.share.logging.internal.perf.SensorTable> <BEA-000000> <Detected that sensors created in an invalid ADFContext were later visible in a valid ADFContext.  The sensors should be created in a valid ADFContext.  Please enable finest logging for more information.> 
<1 Φεβ 2017 2:28:44 μμ EET> <Notice> <LoggingService> <BEA-320400> <The log file C:\Users\l.mitsis\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.1.2.0.40.66.68\DefaultDomain\servers\DefaultServer\logs\DefaultDomain.log will be rotated. Reopen the log file if tailing has stopped. This can happen on some platforms, such as Windows.> 
<1 Φεβ 2017 2:28:44 μμ EET> <Notice> <LoggingService> <BEA-320401> <The log file has been rotated to C:\Users\l.mitsis\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.1.2.0.40.66.68\DefaultDomain\servers\DefaultServer\logs\DefaultDomain.log00352. Log messages will continue to be logged in C:\Users\l.mitsis\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.1.2.0.40.66.68\DefaultDomain\servers\DefaultServer\logs\DefaultDomain.log.> 
<1 Φεβ 2017 2:28:44 μμ EET> <Notice> <Log Management> <BEA-170027> <The server has successfully established a connection with the Domain level Diagnostic Service.> 
<1 Φεβ 2017 2:28:44 μμ EET> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to ADMIN.> 
<1 Φεβ 2017 2:28:44 μμ EET> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to RESUMING.> 
<1 Φεβ 2017 2:28:44 μμ EET> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090171> <Loading the identity certificate and private key stored under the alias DemoIdentity from the kss keystore file kss://system/demoidentity.> 
<1 Φεβ 2017 2:28:46 μμ EET> <Notice> <Security> <BEA-090169> <Loading trusted certificates from the kss keystore file kss://system/trust.> 
<1 Φεβ 2017 2:28:46 μμ EET> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "DefaultSecure[2]" is now listening on 127.0.0.1:7102 for protocols iiops, t3s, ldaps, https.> 
<1 Φεβ 2017 2:28:46 μμ EET> <Warning> <Server> <BEA-002611> <The hostname "lmitsis1.ggps.local", maps to multiple IP addresses: 10.30.12.180, fe80:0:0:0:6d3c:6c30:3a08:ba60%3.> 
<1 Φεβ 2017 2:28:46 μμ EET> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[2]" is now listening on 127.0.0.1:7101 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<1 Φεβ 2017 2:28:46 μμ EET> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[1]" is now listening on fe80:0:0:0:6d3c:6c30:3a08:ba60:7101 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<1 Φεβ 2017 2:28:46 μμ EET> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "DefaultSecure" is now listening on 10.30.12.180:7102 for protocols iiops, t3s, ldaps, https.> 
<1 Φεβ 2017 2:28:46 μμ EET> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "DefaultSecure[1]" is now listening on fe80:0:0:0:6d3c:6c30:3a08:ba60:7102 for protocols iiops, t3s, ldaps, https.> 
<1 Φεβ 2017 2:28:46 μμ EET> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default[3]" is now listening on 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:7101 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<1 Φεβ 2017 2:28:46 μμ EET> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "DefaultSecure[3]" is now listening on 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:7102 for protocols iiops, t3s, ldaps, https.> 
<1 Φεβ 2017 2:28:46 μμ EET> <Notice> <Server> <BEA-002613> <Channel "Default" is now listening on 10.30.12.180:7101 for protocols iiop, t3, ldap, snmp, http.> 
<1 Φεβ 2017 2:28:46 μμ EET> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000331> <Started the WebLogic Server Administration Server "DefaultServer" for domain "DefaultDomain" running in development mode.> 
<1 Φεβ 2017 2:28:46 μμ EET> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000365> <Server state changed to RUNNING.> 
<1 Φεβ 2017 2:28:46 μμ EET> <Notice> <WebLogicServer> <BEA-000360> <The server started in RUNNING mode.> 
[Running application TAARequest on IntegratedWebLogicServer...] 
IntegratedWebLogicServer startup time: 119975 ms.
[IntegratedWebLogicServer started.]
[02:28:49 PM] Web Module TAARequestWebApp.war recognized in project TAARequest.jpr
[02:28:50 PM] ----  Deployment started.  ----
[02:28:50 PM] Target platform is  (Weblogic 12.x).
[02:28:51 PM] Retrieving existing application information
[02:28:51 PM] Running dependency analysis...
[02:28:51 PM] Deploying 2 profiles...
[02:28:53 PM] Wrote Web Application Module to C:\Users\l.mitsis\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.1.2.0.40.66.68\o.j2ee\drs\TAARequest\TAARequestWebApp.war
[02:28:55 PM] Wrote Enterprise Application Module to C:\Users\l.mitsis\AppData\Roaming\JDeveloper\system12.1.2.0.40.66.68\o.j2ee\drs\TAARequest
[02:28:56 PM] Deploying Application...
<1 Φεβ 2017 2:29:03 μμ EET> <Error> <Deployer> <BEA-149265> <Failure occurred in the execution of deployment request with ID "1485952136670" for task "0". Error is: "weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gsis.mainmenu.database.GenericServiceImpl_ou0dm7_GenericServiceImpl"
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gsis.mainmenu.database.GenericServiceImpl_ou0dm7_GenericServiceImpl
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:114)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:172)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:167)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver$ParallelChange.run(StateMachineDriver.java:80)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gsis.mainmenu.database.GenericServiceImpl_ou0dm7_GenericServiceImpl
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:335)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:302)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:180)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
<1 Φεβ 2017 2:29:03 μμ EET> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149004> <Failures were detected while initiating deploy task for application "TAARequest".> 
<1 Φεβ 2017 2:29:03 μμ EET> <Warning> <Deployer> <BEA-149078> <Stack trace for message 149004
weblogic.application.ModuleException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gsis.mainmenu.database.GenericServiceImpl_ou0dm7_GenericServiceImpl
    at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.prepare(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:114)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.prepare(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:100)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:172)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$1.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:167)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver$ParallelChange.run(StateMachineDriver.java:80)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.gsis.mainmenu.database.GenericServiceImpl_ou0dm7_GenericServiceImpl
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findLocalClass(GenericClassLoader.java:335)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.findClass(GenericClassLoader.java:302)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:423)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:356)
    at weblogic.utils.classloaders.GenericClassLoader.loadClass(GenericClassLoader.java:180)
    Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
> 
[02:29:03 PM] Deployment cancelled.
[02:29:03 PM] ----  Deployment incomplete  ----.
[02:29:03 PM] Remote deployment failed (oracle.jdevimpl.deploy.common.Jsr88RemoteDeployer)
#### Cannot run application TAARequest due to error deploying to IntegratedWebLogicServer.
[02:29:04 PM] Cancel requested
[Application TAARequest stopped and undeployed from IntegratedWebLogicServer]
```

After this kind of error a file appears under the current project and inside WebContent called _WL_GENERATED. If I delete the file and rerun the app it runs without problem.

Has anybody else seen this behavior in JDeveloper?